# Python data filtering

Tags: python, pandas, date, where-clause

I am trying to make a python script that pulls into a new data frame based on the date of the month and assign it to a dataframe. I'm having trouble with the date logic syntax.

Edit: this is my code so far

-- bringing the data and assigning it to a data frame, I did this 3x

```py
cols = [0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
stage_Associate = pd.concat(pd.read_excel('Campaign Codes.xls', usecols=cols, sheet_name=None, skiprows=[0,4]),ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

--this will assign 3 different data frames into one based on the correct month 
which needs some help

```py
df_Associate = if stage_Associate[6].month = "5" else pass
```

In sql terms it would be something like adding a where column4 = extract (month from column4)

Data structure:

```
1,2,3,4

x,y,z,01/02/2019      
x,y,z,01/02/2019    
x,y,z,02/02/2019    
x,y,z,02/02/2019
```

Comment: Show yuor actual attempted code, don't try to describe it in words.

Comment: Well... **do** try to describe it in words but **also** provide your code.  Think about it this way.  You're asking a question because something is *wrong*.  You think that it is wrong because what you think should be happening isn't what is happening when you run your code.  By providing both, you provide us with both sides of the equation and we can better interpret your intention.